# Elasticsearch must_not terms query for Spring

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a database model for a `user` as:

```
{
    "referenceId": "123",
    "name": "Frank",
    "department": "CS",
    "negativeUserList": [ "980", "739" ]
}
```

I am writing an ES 2.4 Query with which I can perform FTS query on user `name` with given `department` but the result should not contain a user with his ID in `negativeUserList` array. So, in the above object, even if User ID `980` has the same `name` and `department`, he (980) should not appear in searching user's (123) FTS. I have successfully written the **following query which is working good**:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
    "must": {
        "multi_match": {
        "query": "A",
        "fields": [
            "name.ngram"
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": "100%"
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "term": {
        "department": "cs"
        }
    },
    "must_not": {
        "terms": {
        "referenceId": [
            "980",
            "739"
        ]
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

But when I integrate the same with Spring ElasticsearchRepository as:

```
@Query("{ \"query\": { \"bool\": { \"must\": { \"multi_match\": { \"query\": \"?0\", \"fields\": [ \"name.ngram\" ], \"minimum_should_match\": \"100%\" } }, \"filter\": { \"term\": { \"department\": \"?1\" } }, \"must_not\": { \"terms\": { \"referenceId\": [ \"?2\" ] } } } } }")
Page<UserSummary> getFreeTextSearchForUser(String freeText, String currentUserDepartment, List<String> negativeUserList, Pageable pageable);
```

Then I do not get any results when `currentUserDepartment` is `cs` and `negativeUserList` is `[ "980", "739" ]` despite of getting results when I run the native query on ES REST endpoint directly.

As of now, most of the users have an empty array in `negativeUserList` and it should run normally.

EDIT:

When I modify the Spring query with:

```
{ \"referenceId\": \"?2\" }
```

i.e. without the square brackets around `\"?2\"`, I get an error as:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [terms] query does not support [referenceId]
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.TermsQueryParser.parse(TermsQueryParser.java:155)
```

If I now remove the double-quotes:

```
{ \"referenceId\": ?2 }
```

I simply do not get back any results but no error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that those two queries are not the same: in native query `referenceId` is an array with two elements (["980","739"]) and in sprinq `referenceId` is an array with one element ([ \"?2\" ], even if ?2 is expanded afterwards.)

Comment: @banuj I tried some more variants of the query and added it to the OP. Should that have made a difference?

Comment: You should search how to expand an array in Spring template.